# Setting imageview using picasso in listview android java

Tags: android-arrayadapter, picasso

Im setting my imageview using picasso, because I just have url for my image. I have using listview to display. In custom adapter I'm setting imageview using picasso. But image is not displayed in listview. I doesn't know where the problem is... Anybody help out to solve this.... Thanks in advance

```
public class GetReportAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsReport> {
    private ArrayList<NewsReport> newsReports;
    public GetReportAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsReport> newsReportArrayList)
    {
        super(context, 0,newsReportArrayList);
        this.newsReports=newsReportArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        NewsReport currentReport=getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
        titleTextView.setText(currentReport.getTitle());
        TextView channelTextView=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.news_channel_text_view);
        channelTextView.setText(currentReport.getChannel());
        ImageView pictureImageView=(ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.news_pic_image_view);
        Log.e("image urlString",currentReport.getImage());
        Picasso.with(listItemView.getContext()).load(currentReport.getImage()).into(pictureImageView);
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Here Im setting listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final Uri CONTENT_URL = Uri.parse("content://com.example.newsreport/newsfeed");
    ContentResolver resolver;
    ArrayList<NewsReport> newsReportArrayList = new ArrayList<NewsReport>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        resolver = getContentResolver();
        Log.e("resolver", "" + resolver);
        getNewsFeed();
        setAdapter();
    }

    public void getNewsFeed() {
        String id = null;
        String title = null;
        String content = null;
        String channel = null;
        String image = null;

        String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, "title", "channel", "image", "content"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URL, projection, null, null, null);
        String newsFeed = "";
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            do {
                id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
                Log.e("title", title);
                content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
                Log.e("content", "" + content);
                channel = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("channel"));
                Log.e("channel", "" + channel);
                image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
                Log.e("image", "" + image);
                newsReportArrayList.add( new NewsReport(channel,title,image));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        }
    }
    public void setAdapter()
    {
        ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        GetReportAdapter adapter= new GetReportAdapter(this,newsReportArrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```